# Proof that dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to the group generated by two group elements of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

An exercise in Aluffi asks the reader to prove that if $a,b$ are distinct elements of order 2 in a group $G$ and $ab$ has finite order $n\geq3$, then the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a,b$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_{2n}$, having already shown that $\langle x,y~|~x^2,y^2,(xy)^n\rangle$ is a presentation of $D_{2n}$.

This is intuitively obvious to me, but I'm having some trouble with a detail of the proof. My strategy is the following:

Let $H=\langle a,b\rangle$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $S=\{x,y\}$. Also let $\mathscr{R}=\{x^2,y^2,(xy)^n\}$ be a subset of $F(S)$, and let $R$ be the normal closure of $\mathscr{R}$ in $F(S)$.
Define a set-function $f:S\to H$ by $x\mapsto a$ and $y\mapsto b$, and extend this to a homomorphism $\rho:F(S)\to H$. I want to prove that $\ker\rho = R$, and hence that $H\cong F(S)/R$ as desired (by the first isomorphism theorem).

Proving that $R\subseteq \ker\rho$ was easy, but I'm having some trouble showing that $\ker\rho\subseteq R$.

How should I approach this? Is there a better overall strategy for the proof?

Comment: So you want the injectivity shown. It is clear $\rho$ is surjective map. So find a map from $H$ to $F(S)/R$ and check its well definedness. You have an obvious choice of the map. The composition $F(S)/R\to H\to F(S)/R$ will become identity on $F(S)/R$.

Comment: @user45765 Hmm, I see - here we're trying to explicitly establish an isomorphism between $H$ and $F(S)/R$, I take it? I'm having trouble showing that the obvious map $H\to F(S)/R$ is well-defined. I guess I need a bit of practice working with multiple generating elements in general. That, or I'm missing something obvious.

Just to be clear, by the way, in the OP I'm trying to invoke the first isomorphism theorem explicitly with $\rho : F(S)\to H$.

Comment: It suffices to check the morphism on $y^l(xy)^kx^m$ as every element of $H$ is a product of $x,y$ but $x^2=y^1=$.

Comment: @user45765 Why does this suffice? Also,  I assume you mean $x^2=y^2=(xy)^n$?

There was a typo in my definition of $H$ - hopefully this has not caused any confusion. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, you still have the same relations maintained. Every element of $H$ can be written in terms of $b^l(ab)^ka^m$'s form for any $l,k,m$. Say $f:H\to F(S)/R$. If $f(b^l(ab)^ka^m)=f(b)^lf(ab)^kf(a)^m$, you are done in the sense you still need to check the multiplication of two elements by $f(cd)=f(c)f(d)$ where $c,d\in H$. This already give you the form of $c$ and $d$. In general, this trick does not work.